# How do I get id from url for Angular Resolver component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm using a resolver component but I cannot get the id from the url.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4djgz

In the stackblitz if I navigate to `supplier/3`:

I get `params.get('id') null` from the resolver and `params.get('id') 3` from the end component. How do I get the endpoint id inside the resolver.

```
route.paramMap.subscribe(
    (params: ParamMap) => {
      console.log("params.get('id')", params.get('id'));
    }
);
```

***This question has been heavily edited as I thought originally this had something to do with being an angular+electron app.***

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Comment: @RobinWebb it was this post that led me astray in the first place. They just use a plain resolve()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the Angular doc](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), as you can see in example in the [guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard), the `resolve` method takes two parameters that are relative to the actual route your are trying to resolve.

Using this in the resolver fixes the problem:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    console.log("params.get('id')", route.paramMap.get('id'));
    return of('dummy').pipe(delay(50));
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4fkspm

Answer (score 2):

You can get the id in the resolver with the snippet below,

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
: Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    let id = route.params['id'];
    return this.service.get(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(
     (params) => {
       console.log("params.get('id')", params['id']);
     });
  }
```